# Azure VPN client azure active directory authentication

Tags: azure, openvpn, azure-vpn

I am trying to implement a azure vpn to have a better understanding of the functionality of this resource.

Following azure documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-tenant

I am able to create all the resources and configure the azure vpn client.

I Downloaded the client and azure vpn, and imported the xml file and tried to connect.

Everything worked fine as I was able to login with my azure credential and connect to the vpn.

But here is the bit that I am a bit confused about.

Once the vpn established the connection, I got a IP address. so I thought that if I go on google to check my IP address, I would get the vpn address, but what I am seeing is my personal ip.

So maybe somebody can help me to understand how can I make sure that the vpn I am connecting to is actually working and generating a tunnel connection from my pc to azure AAD?

Please if my question Is not 100% clear, just ask for more information.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure P2S VPN connections do not support forced tunnelling so you will still be routing to the Internet from your local public IP address and not via Azure.

For testing, if you deploy a private resource in Azure such as a virtual machine then you should be able to access it via it's private IP address to confirm your VPN is working correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question. When you say private resource, what do you refer to exactly? Like a vm?

Comment: Yes, private so that it can only be accessed over the VPN connection and not over the Internet by a public IP address.  So if you create a VM in Azure then you should be able to connect to it using its private IP address if you are connected to the VPN.

Comment: Yes that worked. I created a vm inside a subnet and I could connect to it using the private ip. and I was able to do so only through vpn. Pardon me for this extra question but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. While connected to azure vpn client, is my connection encrypted even if I am browsing?

Comment: Traffic over the VPN is encrypted but if you are browsing the Internet then this traffic is going straight out to the Internet so would not be encrypted by your VPN.  The purpose of the P2S VPN that you are using is for accessing private (non-public) Azure resources not for privately browsing the Internet.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you very much for your explanation